# Is @Component({ ... }) actually a regular function call?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

In Angular, you use `@Component({ selector: '...', ... })` when creating a new component.

I am just curious what this **@Component** actually is. Just a normal function call? Is this a valid name for a normal function?

I was even more confused, when I tried naming a function **@test** which worked in a JSFiddle, but somehow was neither correct JavaScript nor TypeScript code:

https://jsfiddle.net/2tsda7h8/

Comment: It's a special kind of function called a decorator, you can read about them in the typescript docs. There are class decorators, property decorators, and method decorators.